# ConstantFolding doesn't work is Spark SQL Catalyst Optimizer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

`ConstantFolding` is a operator optimization rule in Catalyst that replaces expressions that can be statically evaluated with their equivalent literal values. This object is a logical plan optimization rule in Operator Optimizations batch in the base Optimizer class.

Maybe I'm missing something but ... why this code bellow doesn't optimize ?

```
val xyzDataFrame = Seq((1, 3, 4)).toDF("x", "y", "z")
xyzDataFrame.selectExpr("(((1 + 3 + 4 + x) + (2 + y) + 3) + x) + z").explain(true)
```

The result is

```
17/12/23 19:14:32 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: (((1 + 3 + 4 + x) + (2 + y) + 3) + x) + z
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [(((((((1 + 3) + 4) + 'x) + (2 + 'y)) + 3) + 'x) + 'z) AS (((((((1 + 3) + 4) + x) + (2 + y)) + 3) + x) + z)#317]
+- Project [_1#306 AS x#310, _2#307 AS y#311, _3#308 AS z#312]
   +- LocalRelation [_1#306, _2#307, _3#308]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
(((((((1 + 3) + 4) + x) + (2 + y)) + 3) + x) + z): int
Project [(((((((1 + 3) + 4) + x#310) + (2 + y#311)) + 3) + x#310) + z#312) AS (((((((1 + 3) + 4) + x) + (2 + y)) + 3) + x) + z)#317]
+- Project [_1#306 AS x#310, _2#307 AS y#311, _3#308 AS z#312]
   +- LocalRelation [_1#306, _2#307, _3#308]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
LocalRelation [(((((((1 + 3) + 4) + x) + (2 + y)) + 3) + x) + z)#317]

== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan [(((((((1 + 3) + 4) + x) + (2 + y)) + 3) + x) + z)#317]
```

I expected something like this:

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
LocalRelation [(13 + (2 * x)  + y + z)#317]
```

EDIT

Example using Dataset:

```
case class XYZ(id: Int, x:Int, y:Int, z:Int)
val xyz_objectDataset = Seq(XYZ(1, 2, 5, 3)).toDS
xyz_objectDataset.select(lit(3) + lit(2)).explain(true)
. . . 
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
LocalRelation [(3 + 2)#528]
```

don't optimize, but this bellow do

```
val java_lang_longDataset= spark.range(1)
java_lang_longDataset.select(lit(3) + lit(2)).explain(true)
...
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [5 AS (3 + 2)#532]
```

---

Any idea ?